# Wordpress is not getting values from database when call it in functions.php file

Tags: database, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to loop through my custom query and making a new array from the results obtained from that query but it returns null when I run

> **new WP_Query($args)**

tried a lot to debug don't know what is the thing that is causing this issue here is what I have treid so far

```
function getProductbySize(){
$category = $_REQUEST['category'];
$size = $_REQUEST['sized'];
$user_id = get_current_user_id();

$args = array(
            'post_type'             => 'product',
            'post_status'           => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page'        => '-1',
            'author'                => $user_id,
            'tax_query'             => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy'      => 'product_cat',
                    'field'         => 'term_id',
                    'terms'         => $category,
                    'operator'      => 'AND'
                ),
                array(
                    'taxonomy'      => 'Size',
                    'field'         => 'term_id',
                    'terms'         => $size,
                )
            )
        );
        $products = new WP_Query($args);

        // var_dump($products);
        $data_array = [];
        $data = [];
        foreach($products as $product){
            $data_array[] = the_ID();
            $data_array[] = the_content();
            $data_array[] = the_permalink();

            $data[] = $data_array;
        }

        var_dump($data_array);
    }
    add_action('wp_ajax_getProductbySize', 'getProductbySize');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_getProductbySize', 'getProductbySize');
```

When I dump my data array it display something like this

> array(44) {
>     [0]=>
>     NULL
>     [1]=>
>     NULL
>     [2]=>
>     NULL
>     [3]=>
>     NULL
>     [4]=>
>     NULL
>     [5]=>
>     NULL
>     [6]=>
>     NULL
>     [7]=>
>     NULL
>     [8]=>
>     NULL
>     [9]=>
>     NULL
>     [10]=>
>     NULL
>     [11]=>
>     NULL
>     [12]=>
>     NULL
>     [13]=>
>     NULL
>     [14]=>
>     NULL
>     [15]=>
>     NULL
>     [16]=>
>     NULL
>     [17]=>
>     NULL
>     [18]=>
>     NULL
>     [19]=>
>     NULL
>     [20]=>
>     NULL
>     [21]=>
>     NULL
>     [22]=>
>     NULL
>     [23]=>
>     NULL
>     [24]=>
>     NULL
>     [25]=>
>     NULL
>     [26]=>
>     NULL
>     [27]=>
>     NULL
>     [28]=>
>     NULL
>     [29]=>
>     NULL
>     [30]=>
>     NULL
>     [31]=>
>     NULL
>     [32]=>
>     NULL
>     [33]=>
>     NULL
>     [34]=>
>     NULL
>     [35]=>
>     NULL
>     [36]=>
>     NULL
>     [37]=>
>     NULL
>     [38]=>
>     NULL
>     [39]=>
>     NULL
>     [40]=>
>     NULL
>     [41]=>
>     NULL
>     [42]=>
>     NULL
>     [43]=>
>     NULL
>   }

Can anyone help me find out what I am doing wrong Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <?php  


function getProductbySize(){
    $category = $_REQUEST['category'];
    $size = $_REQUEST['sized'];
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();

    $data_array = [];   // Get some random products.
        $args = array(
                'post_type'    => 'product',
                'post_status'  => 'publish',
                'author'       =>  $user_id,
                'product_cat'  =>  $category,
                'posts_per_page'  => '-1', 
                'tax_query'             => array( 
                    array(
                        'taxonomy'      => 'Size',
                        'field'         => 'term_id',
                        'terms'         => $size,
                    )
                )


            );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

                array_push($data_array,array(
                        'title' =>get_the_title(),
                        'content' =>get_the_content(),
                        'permalink' =>get_the_permalink()
                    ));

            endwhile;
        } 

        var_dump($data_array);
    }
    add_action('wp_ajax_getProductbySize', 'getProductbySize');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_getProductbySize', 'getProductbySize');
  ?>
```